# Property type of two classes

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I'm writing session manager class in .NET MVC 4 and I got stuck at the point of creating SqlConfiguration. 
Here is one of the properties from the class:

```
public static MsSqlConfiguration SqlConfig { get; set; }
```

All working perfectly excluding the fact that I can manage sessions only from MS SQLServer.
I want to do something like this:

```
public static MsSqlConfiguration,SQLiteConfiguration SqlConfig { get; set; }
```

And I know it isn't possible so I don't know what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: You want to create an abstraction. `IDatabaseConfiguration`. You could also add a layer of indirection between your session manager and your persistence mechanism.

Comment: @SamLeach Can you show me an example?

Comment: Will you only ever use one or the other? Or both at the same time?

Comment: Please, don't tag question about Microsoft SQL Server with "sql" tag and question about ASP.NET MVC framework with "mvc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a dictionary?

```
public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IPersistenceConfigurer> DbConfigurations = 
    new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, IPersistenceConfigurer>(
        new Dictionary<string, IPersistenceConfigurer>
        {
            { "azure", MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                    .ConnectionString("ConnectionString")
                                    .Dialect<MsSqlAzure2008Dialect>()
                                    .Driver<SqlAzureClientDriver>() },
            { "mssql", MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                    .ConnectionString("ConnectionString")
                                    .Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>() },
            { "sqlite", SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                                            .InMemory() },
            // etc..
        });
```

`IPersistenceConfigurer` is an interface that any database configuration must implement.

As it's a dictionary, you can always check if a database configuration is present by calling `DbConfigurations.ContainsKey("mssql")`.

Another option is using a generic list of `IPersistenceConfigurer` (aka `List<IPersistenceConfigurer>`) and get a configuration using *LINQ* `OfType<T>` extension method as follows:

```
dbConfigs.OfType<MsSqlConfiguration >().Single()
```

...or

```
dbConfigs.Single(config => config is MsSqlConfiguration)
```

Another option, if you're using Dependency Injection and an IoC container such as **[Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)** is to register a factory with the container that can provide an instance of `IPersistenceConfigurer` to any components that require it. This way you can register different components for the `IPersistenceConfigurer` service depending on which environment you are running in (as I assume that you only need one particular `IPersistenceConfigurer` for the application at any one time).

Comment: I don't have any IDbConfig class / interface. I'm using Fluent NHibernate.

Comment: @RafaelZilberman Are you sure? And what's this? https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/Db/IPersistenceConfigurer.cs

Comment: Yes it works but now it still only for MS SQLSERVER. How I making it get the first config that not null?

Comment: @RafaelZilberman I don't understand your question at all. It's not only for SQL Server.

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: @RafaelZilberman I've no time for this now, but if any database configuration implements `IPersistenceConfigurer`, you should be ale to store any database configuration, both in a dictionary or a list of the `IPersistenceConfigurer` generic type.

Comment: @RussCam Thank you for the edit. Maybe you went beyond or too far. If the OP was asking such question I doubt *inversion of control* / *dependency injection* would be part of his/her toolset, you know. Anyway, it's still useful!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer true; I thought it was worth including as an avenue that the OP might like to explore or a different way to think about solving the underlying problem which they might not necessarily be currently familiar with.

Comment: @RussCam Yeah, no problem, you're right. I just wanted to point out that the OP may need to improve his/her skills to leverage your edit. Anyway, this is SO and it should be useful for future readers after all ;) Thank you again.

Comment: @RussCam Ah, and I liked your suggestion about Castle Windsor. It's my container of choice too.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class with these 2 properties and Use them. I know its very basic

```
class MyConfig 
{   
    public static MsSqlConfiguration SqlConfig { get; set; }

    public static SQLiteConfiguration SQLiteConfig { get; set; }
}
```

Use them like

```
public static MyConfig SqlConfig { get; set; }
```

Comment: But if I will do like to saying I need to check what config is empty and what no.

Comment: At some point in your code you need to differentiate between the two, right? So why not at this point?